# How does chsh prevent users from changing another user's shell?

Tags: security, accounts

I know `chsh` is used to change a user's login shell by modifying `/etc/passwd`. So, in principle anyone could run this command and change another user's default shell but that is not allowed.

How is this stopped in `chsh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chsh` is [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid), so it can run in a context that means users can perform actions with root's privilege.  Anything setuid has to be written very carefully to not allow a privilege escalation.  `chsh` is written in C, and it appears to [check that the person running the program is the same as the user that you're asking to change](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/login-utils/chsh.c#n284).